# UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera crashes in IPHONE Simulator?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it a known issue that if you try to test your UIImagePickerController using the Camera as a source type then the simulator will crash?

I have the following code:

```
self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
[self.imgPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
[imgPicker release];
```

Running this in simulator, I get an *objc-exception-throw* error on the stack @ -[UIImagePickerController setSourceType:].

Now if I set the source type to the Photo Library though, everything runs smoothly and fine? What's the deal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simulator doesn't have the camera and can't simulate to take a picture (it would have been nice to use the isight but Apple has not been so kindly). However Your code is not safe because, for example, old ipod touch doesn't have a camera and in this case your app will crash on this device.

As Apple suggest in [UIImagePickerController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html):

> To use an image picker controller
> containing its default controls,
> perform these steps:
>
> **1.Verify that the device is capable of picking content from the
> desired source. Do this calling the
> isSourceTypeAvailable: class method,
> providing a constant from the
> “UIImagePickerControllerSourceType”
> enum.**
>
> 2.Check which media types are available, for the source type you’re
> using, by calling the
> availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
> class method. This lets you
> distinguish between a camera that can
> be used for video recording and one
> that can be used only for still
> images.
>
> 3.Tell the image picker controller to adjust the UI according to the
> media types you want to make
> available—still images, movies, or
> both—by setting the mediaTypes
> property.
>
> 4.Present the user interface by calling the
> presentModalViewController:animated:
> method of the currently active view
> controller, passing your configured
> image picker controller as the new
> view controller.
>
> 5.When the user taps a button to pick a newly-captured or saved image
> or movie, or cancels the operation,
> dismiss the image picker using your
> delegate object. For newly-captured
> media, your delegate can then save it
> to the Camera Roll on the device. For
> previously-saved media, your delegate
> can then use the image data according
> to the purpose of your app.

So you have to call `isSourceTypeAvailable` and set your sourceType consistently.

Comment: So the answer is YES, it does indeed crash in the simulator because it has no camera :) Worked fine on iphone for testing. Understood with the source type testing, although is it really necessary if you plan to make your app exclusive to camera devices?

Comment: I think you can specify in your info.plist the Required Device Capabilities with the key 'still-camera'. But I strongly recommend you to do the check because, as the documentations says about the isSourceTypeAvailable method "if the camera is already in use, this method returns NO"...this means that if your device have a camera this doesn't mean that you can use it everytime you want. So handle the error gently your user will thank you

Comment: But the isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera returns YES. Still crash on simulator.